# Angularjs and pusher socket_id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pusher

I'm working on a single page application using laravel and angularjs where I'll use pusher to get notification. I'm struggling to get my socket_id at my AngularJs side, here's my code...

```
var client = new Pusher('MY-KEY');
var pusher = $pusher(client);

var channel = pusher.subscribe('notifications');
    pusher.bind('new-notification',
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
);

console.log(clint.connection.socket_id);
```

I can get the notification from server, but I can't get the socket_id from my angular.

I have tried the following:

```
console.log(client.connection.socket_id); //get undefined
console.log(client.connection); // get b {callbacks: c, global_callbacks: Array[0], failThrough: undefined, key: "MY-PUSHER-KEY", options: Object…}
```

Hope there's anyone out there who can help me.

Answer (score 1):

The `pusher.connection.socket_id` value is only set once the connection has been established.

Try:

```
pusher.connnection.bind('connected', function() {
  console.log(pusher.connection.socket_id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like below

```
this._pusher.connection.bind('connected', function(data) 
  {
        console.log( data.socket_id );
  }
);
```